# Symlink inside sysfs

Tags: linux-kernel

I trying to adapt 4.9 msm8953 kernel [1] for my phone - Xiaomi Redmi Note 4x. It was originally shipped with kernel 3.18.

Kernel almost done, however one of the last problems is changed sysfs structure [2]:
in kernel 3.18 FPC fingerprint device path was `/sys/devices/soc/soc:fpc1020`, but in 4.9 it is now in `/sys/devices/platform/soc/soc:fpc1020`. This is a problem for proprietary userland, which is hard to change.

So the goal is to symlink `/sys/devices/platform/soc/soc:fpc1020` to `/sys/devices/soc/soc:fpc1020`.

For what I see there is no public API to directly create nodes inside `/sys/devices`.

Any advices how to get kobject of `/sys/devices` and make sysfs symlink here?

[1] https://github.com/nE0sIghT/android_kernel_xiaomi_msm8953
[2] https://github.com/nE0sIghT/android_kernel_xiaomi_msm8953/issues/18

Answer (score 0):

I was able to create symbolic link using `kernfs_create_link` and getting parent kernfs node through `parent` property.
Here is solution: https://github.com/nE0sIghT/android_kernel_xiaomi_msm8953/commit/5749d673cce1e2ab2bdeb2f689d1527143889a05